# installation of package ‘Rmpfr’ had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, installation, package

Please help me to install Rmpfr package in R. 
The result is:
installation of package ‘Rmpfr’ had non-zero exit status and I am unable to install it.

The code from R console is posted below:

```
* installing *source* package ‘Rmpfr’ ...
** package ‘Rmpfr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking mpfr.h usability... no
checking mpfr.h presence... no
checking for mpfr.h... no
configure: error: Header file mpfr.h not found; maybe use --with-mpfr-include=INCLUDE_PATH
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rmpfr’
* removing ‘/home/fbn/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rmpfr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rmpfr’ had non-zero exit status
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you install the [mpfr library](http://www.mpfr.org/)? The [description of the package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/Rmpfr.pdf) states: `SystemRequirementsNote MPFR (MP Floating-Point Reliable Library,
http://mpfr.org/) and GMP (GNU Multiple Precision library,
http://gmplib.org/)`,

Comment: Thank you RHertel for your response, I am using R in elementary OS - libmpfr4 and libgmp-dev and libmpc3 are installed as reported from synaptic package manager

Comment: Problem solved. I installed some libraries as suggested in http://askubuntu.com/questions/394296/how-to-install-mpfr-3-1-2-in-ubuntu-13-04: sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev libmpfr-doc libmpfr4 libmpfr4-dbg . Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 11):

Try installing libmpfr-dev from terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev
```

Then again install 'Rmpfr' from R

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked very well. Why do you have to install this using the terminal?